# Why does Kaspersky intercept certificates?

Tags: firefox, certificate, kaspersky

After a fresh install of Firefox, I had to find the Kaspersky certificate in Windows 10 and to export it. After, I imported it in Firefox (in "options" search for "certificate"). Before that, Firefox wouldn't open Youtube or Google, saying they were not trusted…

Why the hassle? AFAIK, Firefox can check certificates. It does so in Ubuntu, where there is no Kaspersky. So why can't Kaspersky just leave certificates alone and transmit them to Firefox? Is there any advantage?

Answer (score 2):

Kaspersky plays [man-in-the-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) so it can read communication that should be kept private. The **reason** for this is that they claim that malicious communication can be identified. It is done by breaking the crypto system…

Comment: So Firefox was right :). Maybe I should get rid of Kasperski. Does it report home?

Comment: Probably. I see a bigger issue in the fact that such systems had security issues themselves, which can be used by hackers to show you a website and make you think it is the real one, beside the fact that ALL tragic can be read by the man in the middle.

Comment: Penetration to the encrypted traffic can be easily disabled, so no MITM approach will be used at all.

Comment: I'm not sure... I can "disable" it and maybe it will still do it... I've got nothing particular to hide, but I hate being spied upon. I feel as though someone walked up to my house and started staring in through the window. Oh well, it's not my usual machine, normally I use Kubuntu.